# I want to know the source for learning this location type declaration

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

```
        title = title_element = parent_element[i].find_element('xpath',**'./../div[1]//div[1]//span[1]'**).text

        defi = def_element = parent_element[i].find_element('xpath',**'.'**).text

        snippet = snip_element = parent_element[i].find_element('xpath',**'./../div'**).text
```

the location tags for the particular title, snippet and definition, I would want to learn how to develop those address **'./../div[1]//div[1]//span[1]'**, if there is any source or a youtube video please share.

I was unable to search for any solution on, maybe I don't have the right keyword to search this.

Comment: Maybe if you show the underlying HTML/XML and tell us what you're trying to extract someone may be able to help you

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Search with xpath keyword in the browser and you will find multiple resources related to it.

**2.** Following link contains examples related to xpaths.

https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html

**3.** You may use xpath helper chrome extension in your browser to write the xpaths easily.

Xpath helper : https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/xpath-helper/hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl