# Webscrapping ESPN prediction odds and money lines

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I keep running into trouble trying to scrap the ESPN website with BeautifulSoup: here is my code down below. For some reason I can't get even the names of the teams to be extracted let alone the money lines for each team.

```
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

def extract_money_lines(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    bs = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    # Extracting team names
    teams = bs.find_all('span', {'class': 'rteQ'})
    if len(teams) < 2:
        return None, None, None, None
    home_team = teams[0].text.strip()
    away_team = teams[1].text.strip()

    # Extracting money lines
    money_lines = bs.find_all('div', {'id': 'topOdd'})
    if len(money_lines) < 2:
        return None, None, None, None
    home_money_line = money_lines[0].text.strip()
    away_money_line = money_lines[1].text.strip()

    return home_team, away_team, home_money_line, away_money_line

# Example NBA game ID
game_id = "401585432"
url = f"https://www.espn.com/nba/game/_/gameId/{game_id}"

# Extract money lines and team names
home_team, away_team, home_money_line, away_money_line = extract_money_lines(url)

# Create DataFrame
data = {
    'Home Team': [home_team],
    'Home Money Line': [home_money_line],
    'Away Team': [away_team],
    'Away Money Line': [away_money_line]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)


# Save DataFrame to CSV
#df.to_csv('nba_money_lines.csv', index=False)
#print("CSV file saved successfully.")
```

For some reason I can't get even the names of the teams to be extracted let alone the money lines for each team. I've looked more in detail on other webscrappers, but am fairly new to this so might explain my trouble. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your initial issue is `teams = bs.find_all('span', {'class': 'rteQ'})` returns 0 objects. Also, I just to the page, Idon't see any where that it states the money line.

None the less, I personally would just go through their api. You may need to look around in that data to find what you need, but the odds are empty there in the summary of the games. But it is available in the scoreboard api. You just need to pass in a date.

```
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

def extract_money_lines(url, dateStr):
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/122.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
    payload = {
        'sport': 'basketball',
        'league': 'nba',
        'region': 'us',
        'lang': 'en',
        'contentorigin': 'espn',
        'buyWindow': '1m',
        'showAirings': 'buy,live,replay',
        'tz': 'America/New_York',
        'dates': dateStr}
    
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload).json()
    events = response['sports'][0]['leagues'][0]['events']
    
    df = pd.json_normalize(events,
                           record_path=['competitors'],
                           meta=['odds', ['odds', 'away', 'moneyLine'], ['odds', 'home', 'moneyLine']],
                           errors='ignore')
    
    

    return df


dateStr = '20240301'
url = f"https://site.web.api.espn.com/apis/v2/scoreboard/header"

# Extract money lines and team names
df = extract_money_lines(url, dateStr)
```

**Output: (with just money lines and teams)**

```
print(df[['homeAway', 'displayName', 'odds.away.moneyLine', 'odds.home.moneyLine']])
   homeAway             displayName odds.away.moneyLine odds.home.moneyLine
0      away     Cleveland Cavaliers                -400                 320
1      home         Detroit Pistons                -400                 320
2      away       Charlotte Hornets                 450                -650
3      home      Philadelphia 76ers                 450                -650
4      away        Dallas Mavericks                 340                -440
5      home          Boston Celtics                 340                -440
6      away   Golden State Warriors                -140                 120
7      home         Toronto Raptors                -140                 120
8      away  Portland Trail Blazers                 120                -140
9      home       Memphis Grizzlies                 120                -140
10     away        Sacramento Kings                 200                -240
11     home  Minnesota Timberwolves                 200                -240
12     away          Indiana Pacers                 180                -210
13     home    New Orleans Pelicans                 180                -210
14     away         Milwaukee Bucks                -175                 150
15     home           Chicago Bulls                -175                 150
16     away      Washington Wizards                 800               -1400
17     home             LA Clippers                 800               -1400
```

**Reshaped:**

```
# New DataFrame with reshaped structure
reshaped_data = []

for i in range(0, len(df), 2):
    row_away = df.iloc[i]
    row_home = df.iloc[i+1]
    reshaped_row = {
        'away': f"{row_away['displayName']}",
        'home': f"{row_home['displayName']}",
        'odds.away.moneyLine': row_away['odds.away.moneyLine'],
        'odds.home.moneyLine': row_home['odds.home.moneyLine']
    }
    reshaped_data.append(reshaped_row)

reshaped_df = pd.DataFrame(reshaped_data)
print(reshaped_df.to_string())
                     away                    home  odds.away.moneyLine  odds.home.moneyLine
0     Cleveland Cavaliers         Detroit Pistons                 -400                  320
1       Charlotte Hornets      Philadelphia 76ers                  450                 -650
2        Dallas Mavericks          Boston Celtics                  340                 -440
3   Golden State Warriors         Toronto Raptors                 -140                  120
4  Portland Trail Blazers       Memphis Grizzlies                  120                 -140
5        Sacramento Kings  Minnesota Timberwolves                  200                 -240
6          Indiana Pacers    New Orleans Pelicans                  180                 -210
7         Milwaukee Bucks           Chicago Bulls                 -175                  150
8      Washington Wizards             LA Clippers                  800                -1400
```

Answer (score 0):

The response from the **requests** is not proper. It is giving **403 status_code** and that's why you are not able to extract any data from the site.
You can pass necessary headers to get the proper response from **requests**.
Here's a revised version of the code with some adjustments.

```py
import bs4
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import etree
import pandas as pd

def extract_money_lines(url):
    response = get_response_using_headers(url)
    bs = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    dom = etree.HTML(str(bs))
    
    # Extracting team names
    team_xpath = "//span[contains(@class,'RMSX')]"
    teams = dom.xpath(team_xpath)
    # teams = bs.find_all('span', {'class': 'RMSX'})
    if len(teams) < 2:
        return None, None, None, None
    home_team = teams[0].text.strip()
    away_team = teams[1].text.strip()

    # Extracting money lines
    money_line_xpath = "//div[contains(@class,'mLAS VZTD jIRH QNwm')]//div[contains(@id,'topOdd')]"
    money_lines = dom.xpath(money_line_xpath)
    # money_lines = bs.find_all('div', {'id': 'topOdd'})
    if len(money_lines) < 2:
        return None, None, None, None
    home_money_line = money_lines[0].text.strip()
    away_money_line = money_lines[1].text.strip()

    return home_team, away_team, home_money_line, away_money_line

# Passing all the necessary headers to get the proper response
def get_response_using_headers(url):
    headers = {
        'authority': 'www.espn.com',
        'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
        'accept-language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.9',
        'sec-ch-ua': '"Not A(Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="121", "Chromium";v="121"',
        'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
        'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
        'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
        'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
        'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
        'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
        'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    }

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    return response

# Example NBA game ID
game_id = "401585477"
url = f"https://www.espn.com/nba/game/_/gameId/{game_id}"

# Extract money lines and team names
home_team, away_team, home_money_line, away_money_line = extract_money_lines(url)

# Create DataFrame
data = {
    'Home Team': [home_team],
    'Home Money Line': [home_money_line],
    'Away Team': [away_team],
    'Away Money Line': [away_money_line]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
```

**Note:** If these are not the expected values then you can write your own xpaths. Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78033634) for xpaths related stuff.